# Apache 2.4 Reverse proxy to Node Application on Docker

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy

I have a dedicated server on Apache 2.4 and I made a node application which is running on a Docker container and listenning on the port `5847`

So I am trying to configure my apache to make a reverse Proxy to `http://my.url.com:5847` on a **Debian 8** machine

When I made this, I have the start page of apache "It Works" but not my application. Of course, If I check `http://my.url.com:5847` in my navigator, it works fine, but why my reverse Proxy doesn't work?

This is my `my.url.com.conf` apache config file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin hello@my-url.com
    ServerName my.url.com
    ProxyPass "/" "http://my.url.com:5847/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://my.url.com:5847/"
</VirtualHost>
```

So I'm quite desesperate, I also tried to add

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

I also tried with `Required all granted`, I tried with the `<Location />` directive, with `ProxyRequests Off` and `On` too but **nothing** is working and I don't understand what is going wrong...

Can you help me please? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: Oups sorry, it's a Debian 8

Answer (score 1):

This wks for me (apache 2.4, node.js runs in 192.168.32.35 on port 3003), on Debian 8

```
<VirtualHost feed.mydomain.net:3003>
    ServerName feed.mydomain.net
    ServerAdmin yves@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://192.168.32.35:3003/
        ProxyPassReverse http://feed.mydomain.net:3003/
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    LogLevel trace1 ssl:warn rewrite:trace1

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi @YvesLeBorg thanks for your configuration file, I already did something like this and didn't work... I found my mistake, I was writting a conf file without *.conf* extension and in `sites-enabled` rather than in `sites-available` so my bad... My configuration file was working good, but was not interpreted by apache...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so ... I think I found my error, I was writing an conf archive without *.conf* extension in `sites-enabled` and that's why apache wasn't taking my configuration... I re-made my configuration file in `sties-enabled` and then enabled it from apache with `a2ensite my.url.com.conf` and now it works...

Sorry for the bas question, nothing to do with reverse proxy!